# Weblogic - Oracle DB - SQLException - Interrupt task is already scheduled for the thread - and the type SO_TIMEOUT

Tags: oracle, jdbc, weblogic12c

We are getting below error frequently while trying to connect to Oracle DB and execute a query. This results in 'cannot obtain connection error'.
The **Failed Reserve Request Count** of Data Source is also increasing when this happens. 
We are not sure if this is due to **network issue** or the **DB issue** or **JDBC driver issue**?

```
and the type SO_TIMEOUT
```

We even increased the connection pool size and ulimit numbers. Looked like the occurrence of the error was reduced, but it is coming back again.

Any idea where the issue could be? Thanks in advance.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDeadException: Interrupt task is already scheduled for the thread Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '87' for queue: 
'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads] and the type SO_TIMEOUT
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.checkAndReturnResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1865)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.checkAndReturnResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1795)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResourceInternal(ResourcePoolImpl.java:428)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:360)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.HAConnectionPool.reserve(HAConnectionPool.java:351)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.HAConnectionPool.reserve(HAConnectionPool.java:242)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPoolManager.reserve(ConnectionPoolManager.java:148)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPoolManager.reserve(ConnectionPoolManager.java:94)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getXAConnectionFromPool(DataSource.java:1902)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.refreshXAConnAndEnlist(DataSource.java:1609)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnectionInternal(DataSource.java:520)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:497)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnectionInternal(RmiDataSource.java:614)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:594)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:587)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.jta.JtaTransaction.init(JtaTransaction.java:68)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.jta.JtaTransaction.getConnection(JtaTransaction.java:131)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForObject(MappedStatement.java:120)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:518)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:493)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:106)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapClientImpl.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug at My Oracle Support with JDBC driver Version 12.2.0.0.0 and later about query timeout.
Take a look at the note

> Oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout Prevents Proper Query Timeout Handling,
>   Causing Connection Leak (Doc ID 2561983.1)

Comment: is there any solution for this bug/issue?